# Issue with child table - MySql query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am having a trouble with my below query , the sales order item is a child table inside the sales order table , those tables (sales order item) which has more than one row displays only the first item I mean the first row and all the other rows are not getting displayed . Please shed some light guys.

```
select 
 `tabSales Order`.`name` as "Sales Order:Link/Sales Order:120",
`tabSales Order`.`customer` as "Customer:Link/Customer:120",
 `tabSales Order Item`.item_code as "Item:Link/Item:120",
`tabSales Order Item`.item_name as "Des:Link/Item:120",
`tabSales Order Item`.qty as "Qty:Int:100",
 `tabSales Order Item`.delivered_qty as "Delivered Qty:Int:100",
 (`tabSales Order Item`.qty - ifnull(`tabSales Order Item`.delivered_qty, 0)) as "Qty to Deliver:Int:140",
`tabSales Order Item`.date as "Sch date:Date:100",
`tabItem`.thumbnail as "Cut wt:Data:60",
(`tabSales Order Item`.qty * `tabItem`.thumbnail) as "Tonnage:Float:80",
`tabProduct master`.grade as "Grade:Data:100",
`tabProduct master`.dieno as "Die no:Data:100",
`tabProduct master`.hammer as "Hammer:Data:50",
`tabProduct master`.rm_idl_cs as "Idl sec:Data:60",
`tabProduct master`.rm_alt_cs as "Alt sec:Data:60",
ifnull(SUM(CASE WHEN `tabSales Order`.`name` = `tabProduction Order`.`sales_order` and `tabSales Order Item`.`item_code` = `tabProduction Order`.`production_item`
         THEN `tabProduction Order`.`qty`
    END),0) as "Issued:Int:80",
SUM(CASE WHEN `tabSales Order`.`name` = `tabProduction Order`.`sales_order` and `tabSales Order Item`.`item_code` = `tabProduction Order`.`production_item`
         THEN `tabProduction Order`.`produced_qty`
    END) as "Cut:Int:80",
(`tabSales Order Item`.qty - ifnull(SUM(CASE WHEN `tabSales Order`.`name` = `tabProduction Order`.`sales_order` and `tabSales Order Item`.`item_code` = `tabProduction Order`.`production_item`
         THEN `tabProduction Order`.`qty`
    END),0)) as "To be issued:Int:80"

    from  `tabSales Order`
    LEFT JOIN  `tabSales Order Item`  ON ( `tabSales Order Item`.`parent` = `tabSales Order`.`name`
              and  `tabSales Order`.docstatus = 1  )
    LEFT JOIN  `tabItem`  ON `tabItem`.`item_code` = `tabSales Order Item`.`item_code`
    LEFT JOIN  `tabProduct master`  ON `tabProduct master`.`part_no` = `tabSales Order Item`.`item_code`
    LEFT JOIN  `tabProduction Order`
               ON (`tabSales Order Item`.`item_code` = `tabProduction Order`.`production_item`
              and  `tabSales Order`.`name` = `tabProduction Order`.`sales_order` )
    where  `tabSales Order`.status not in ("Stopped", "Closed", "Completed" )
      and  ifnull(`tabSales Order Item`.delivered_qty,0) < ifnull(`tabSales Order Item`.qty,  0 )
    GROUP BY  `tabSales Order`.`name`
    HAVING  (`tabSales Order Item`.qty -
                SUM(CASE WHEN `tabSales Order`.`name` = `tabProduction Order`.`sales_order`
                      and  `tabSales Order Item`.`item_code` = `tabProduction Order`.`production_item`
                         THEN `tabProduction Order`.`qty` END)
            ) > 0
      or  (`tabSales Order Item`.qty -
                SUM(CASE WHEN `tabSales Order`.`name` = `tabProduction Order`.`sales_order`
                      and  `tabSales Order Item`.`item_code` = `tabProduction Order`.`production_item`
                         THEN `tabProduction Order`.`qty` END)
            ) is NULL;
```

Comment: See if you can use `HAVING IFNULL( ...-SUM(...) , 1)` instead of computing it twice.

Comment: @RickJames . Tried using HAVING IFNULL( ..) but still the issue persists . Any help ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, that was just a simplification suggestion, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, shorten it to make it more readable:

```
    FROM  `tabSales Order` AS so
    LEFT JOIN  `tabSales Order Item` AS soi
               ON ( soi.`parent` = so.`name`
              AND  so.docstatus = 1  )
    LEFT JOIN  `tabItem` AS i  ON i.`item_code` = soi.`item_code`
    LEFT JOIN  `tabProduct master` AS pm
               ON pm.`part_no` = soi.`item_code`
    LEFT JOIN  `tabProduction Order` AS po
               ON (soi.`item_code` = po.`production_item`
              AND  so.`name` = po.`sales_order` )
    WHERE  so.status NOT IN ("Stopped", "Closed", "Completed" )
      AND  IFNULL(soi.delivered_qty,0) < IFNULL(soi.qty,  0 )
    GROUP BY  so.`name`
    HAVING  IFNULL(soi.qty -
                SUM(CASE WHEN so.`name` = po.`sales_order`
                   AND  soi.`item_code` = po.`production_item`
                         THEN po.`qty` END), 1) > 0
```

Then some general analysis, without necessarily solving the problem:

- Do you really need `LEFT`?  That is, is the "right" table optional, and you want the `NULLs` you might get?
- There is a difference between `LEFT JOIN b ON b.x = 1` and `LEFT JOIN b WHERE b.x = 1`.  The former may include more `b` rows than the latter.
- Having `NULLs` is good in many situations, but if you can avoid them, the SQL becomes simpler.

**More**

Start by running it without "GROUP BY  `tabSales Order`.`name`".  You will get your missing lines, but you may get a lot more than you want.  If so, then remove the rest of the joins and let's see if we can add them back in without the 'implosion' of items.

To help with understanding the data, please say whether each of the relationships is 1:1 or 1:many or many:many.

Comment: FWIW, I'd go with 's', 'si', and 'i'

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Rick James . Yes I know but I need to have NULLs in my situation . Any idea why I am not able to get all the rows in the child table ?

Comment: Which table is the "child table"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RickJames . `tabSales Order Item` is the child table . Please help . Any help would really be a life saver.

Comment: see what I added.

Comment: @RickJames . Thanks a ton for the reply , removing the GROUP BY statement does not show any field I think probably it is because I am using an aggregate function in the select statement . The relationship is 1:many . Any help ? Thanks in advance